# How can I decode partially double serialized json string using `Codable` protocol?

Tags: swift, swift4, codable

How can I decode partially double serialized json string using `Codable` protocol?

```
    class Person : Codable {
        var name : String?
        var hobby : String?
    }
    class Family : Codable {
        var person: String?
        var person_: Person?
    }
    class PerfectFamily : Codable {
        var person: Person?
    }

    let jsonString = "{\"person\":\"{\\\"name\\\":\\\"Mike\\\",\\\"hobby\\\":\\\"fishing\\\"}\"}"
    do {
        // I could do this.
        let family = try JSONDecoder().decode(Family.self, from: Data(jsonString.utf8))
        family.person_ = try JSONDecoder().decode(Person.self, from: Data(family.person!.utf8))
        print(family)

        // However I want to write more simply like this. Do you have some idea?
        let perfectFamily = try JSONDecoder().decode(PerfectFamily.self, from: Data(jsonString.utf8)) // error
        print(perfectFamily)

    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
```

Comment: Can you show how you are encoding your JSON?. You should fix your JSON instead of hacking your way decoding it.

Comment: Oh... I see. This json format is a response from server. I can't controll it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't fix your double encoded json you can provide your own custom decoder method to your PerfectFamily class but I recommend using a struct:

---

```
struct Person: Codable {
    let name: String
    let hobby: String
}
```

---

```
struct PerfectFamily: Codable {
    let person: Person
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        let person = try container.decode([String: String].self)["person"] ?? ""
        self.person = try JSONDecoder().decode(Person.self, from: Data(person.utf8))
    }
}
```

---

```
let json = "{\"person\":\"{\\\"name\\\":\\\"Mike\\\",\\\"hobby\\\":\\\"fishing\\\"}\"}"

do {
    let person = try JSONDecoder().decode(PerfectFamily.self, from: Data(json.utf8)).person
    print(person)   // "Person(name: "Mike", hobby: "fishing")\n"
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: First, I was wrong in word, not `double encoded`, `double serialized` was correct.
I discussed with server engineer and we found that `double serialize` was unnecessary, as you said.
But it is impossible to change it immediately because the influence is large. Then I use your idea. Thank you very much. I'm very happy.